# Initiating Bulk TCP connections

Tags: freebsd, tcp-ip

Our company has 2 proxy servers that are running a vendor proprietary OS that is built on top of FreeBSD 11.2, we are having incidents on our business peak hours where proxy server stops accepting new client TCP connections when it reach limit of 60K TCP connections, the vendor is claiming that the proxy can accept 120K connections, we dont have any access to root level of the system and so we cant see any kernel configurations, the only way to validate this is by re-producing the issue out of business hours by initiating "dump" tcp connections from 2-3 other freebsd test machine toward the proxy server to confirm if it will really stop accepting connections when number reachs 60k or not.

is there any tool that i can use on freebsd that would create bulk tcp connections toward certain ip address?

Comment: Well, of course, and there are several which should have been mentioned immediately. Unfortunately, I'm not in a position to answer your question for a couple of days so I hope someone else will today.

Answer (score 0):

I think `netcat` can do that. Please see:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191129/306872

the 2nd part of the example, opening client connections.

(Sorry, couldn't add this as comment).

Comment: if you think that another question answers this one, the correct thing to do is to flag this question as a duplicate of the other. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @JeffSchaller, I'll try to do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Benchmark](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) can be useful to test actual service, and not just connection establishment:

```
ab -c <concurrency> -n <requests_no> -X <proxy_address>  <some reliable HTTP endpoint>
```

I suggest you bring up some private HTTP server and stress load it, and then stress load the proxy to reach that server.

For more complex loads and patterns, you can use [tsung](https://github.com/processone/tsung).